# ES15 Import a library that is a plugin for another library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, import

I'm making a React project but am having trouble with the libraries. I want to import D3 and a plugin for it called d3-3d but whenever I do, d3-3d's native functionality of adding a function to the D3 object doesn't work.

On simpler projects, it works just by plugging in the script tags:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-3d/build/d3-3d.min.js"></script>
```

and then calling a new function placed on `d3` named `_3d`. For example:

```
d3
  ._3d()
  .scale(4)
  .origin(origin)
  .rotateX(startAngle)
  .rotateY(startAngle)
  .primitiveType("POINTS");
```

But for React, no such method is attached. I don't fully understand how  imports and exports work but here is a snippet of the d3-3d source code that is handling its own exports if it helps.

```
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (factory((global.d3 = global.d3 || {})));
}(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';

...

exports._3d = _3d;

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

})));
```

I just want to know how I can get the same functionality as I did with plain script tags inside a react environment where I'm using the import syntax instead.

I already tried something like this

```
import "d3-3d";
```

which I heard is just for the side effects of a library, but that didn't work. Neither did importing it as `d3_3d` and placing the `_3d` method as a property on the d3 object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried `import _3d from "d3-3d"`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that. So I actually tried that first and it didn't work. I mean, it imported and all, but then when I tried calling it where it needed to be called, it threw errors. This is my wild guess but I'm thinking d3-3d is just extending the chaining methods found within d3. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `import * as d3 from 'd3';

import { _3d } from 'd3-3d';

d3._3d = _3d;`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but yes, that code did just the trick! THanks fila.

Comment: great, glad to help, i'll post it as answer so you can resolve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import * as d3 from 'd3'; 
import { _3d } from 'd3-3d'; 
d3._3d = _3d;
```